# Why does my site load slow on my localhost but not on the live site?

Tags: mysql, performance, localhost, mamp

I am currently developing a site on my localhost, using mamp, which I then push up to the live site using git.  Here is my question.  When I refresh the page on my localhost it takes up to a minute to load the page again.  When I refresh the page on the live site it refreshes almost instantly.  On each refresh it does a couple database queries, but nothing big.

I am using a mysql database, a codeigniter framework, and my site is hosted by Hostgator.

Thanks!

Comment: Just start commenting out large sections until it goes faster, then you can narrow it down to the function or class which is causing the problem. You can also use a profiler.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let me say that this is impossible to answer without a lot more information. That being said, my best guess would be that your local MAMP installation doesn't have as much memory allocated as your actual web server. The amount of RAM PHP has access to can be modified in your php.ini file or using `ini_set("memory_limit","256M");`

However, if your host machine doesn't have a lot of RAM to begin with, then this probably won't make a difference...